# Limiting the displayed results in React useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some React code that is filtering my array and displaying the results by what the user searches:

```
function App() {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [filteredCountries, setFilteredCountries] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    axios
      .get("https://www.countriesapi.com")
      .then((res) => {
        setCountries(res.data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredCountries(
      countries.filter((country) =>
        country.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      )
    );
  }, [search, countries]);

  if (loading) {
    return <p>Loading countries...</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Countries Lists</h1>
        <a
          style={{ color: "red" }}
          target="_blank"
          href="https://www.somesite.com"
        >
        </a>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search Countries"
        onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
      />
      {filteredCountries.map((country, idx) => (
        <CountryDetail key={idx} {...country} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

My countries list has 500 results so having them all in the page before the user writes the whole `search` term is not feasible.

How can I display let's say only 10 results in the page, rather than the whole 500?

Thanks

Note: My code has been mirrored by this one if you want to take a look at a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-hooks-search-filter-4gnwc)

Comment: Array.prototype.slice()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Array.prototype.slice()` to get only 10 elements.

```
{filteredCountries.slice(0, 10).map((country, idx) => (
    <CountryDetail key={idx} {...country} />
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can paginate your list on `axios.get("https://www.countriesapi.com")` if [www.countriesapi.com](http://www.countriesapi.com) allows this. Or you can just make countries.slice

```
useEffect(() => {
    const newList = search ? countries : countries.slice(0, 10)
    setFilteredCountries(
       newList.filter((country) =>
          country.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
       )
 );
}, [search, countries]);
```